# Unable to access any variables in gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I'd like to access one of the gitlab CI/CD pre-defined variables, but when I try to use it, I just get the literal string of my attempt to access it. Per [Gitlab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/), the correct syntax is `"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"`, but this isn't working. I also tried creating my own variables, but the same thing is happening. Here are some screenshots of my .gitlab-ci.yml file and the results of it running:
[image: .gitlab-ci.yml file]

[image: Output from running]

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `cmd` batch shell. As described in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-variables-with-windows-batch), you must use `%VARNAME%` instead of `$VARNAME` in your `script:` sections.

```yaml
  script:
    - echo %CI_COMMIT_BRANCH%
```

Answer (score 0):

All depends on the pipeline flow and the version of the runner and even it's OS.

I see that you have a Windows build so you should use POSH/Batch commands not `*nix` shell ones.

> The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

If I remember correct if it can't interpolate "a variable" i.e. if it doesn't exist in the scope of the script at execution time, it just treats it as a string and prints to screen everything after `echo` which is the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by calling the variable the same way as one would in the CMD:
`echo %CI_COMMIT_BRANCH%`

[image: yml file]

[image: results]